# Notation issue - Asymptotic behaviour: is $\sim$ too restrictive?

Tags: analysis, limits, notation, asymptotics

As a student I am completely unable to understand unambiguously what is meant by a notation such as $$f \sim g $$ when in Physics the behaviour of two functions at infinity is evaluated. 
I found a definition according to which the notation is equivalent to stating that $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {f}{g} = 1$$ but is this not too restrictive? 
This then means is not correct to say that $$x^2$$ and $$\frac{1}{2} x^2$$ have  the same asymptotic behaviour at infinity. I find it puzzling.
Thanks
PS: The question is admittedly trivial but an extensive search left it unanswered, so I appeal to your patience...

Comment: If we allowed for $x^{2}\sim \frac{1}{2}x^{2}$, wouldn't this be not restrictive enough to be useful?

Comment: We can say $x^2=O(\frac12 x^2)$ (or the converse).

Comment: The big-O notation is really too weak...

Comment: Physicists are often rather imprecise in their notation, or take mathematical notation and use it, well, incorrectly (one of the worst cases being the infamous $f(\omega)$ as the Fourier transform of $f(x)$). This is another such case: by employing the imprecise use of notation you're talking about, how do you say that two functions are asymptotically equivalent?

Comment: @Bernard: in this case, putting the constant in the $O(\cdot)$ looks really strange. But the analogue of equivalent for a $O(\cdot)$ notation would be $\Theta(\cdot)$, which is both $O(\cdot)$ and $\Omega(\cdot)$: it does not capture exacly the same thing (not exact constant, but between two constants), but is still a good first candidate.

Comment: I wrote it that way  'cause I wanted to use the same functions as the O.P., and the reverse seems useless, as $\frac12<1$. But yes, I agree it looks weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure the following will answer your answer, but by definition, $f \sim g$ (implicitly, at $+\infty$) if $|f(x) - g(x)| = o(|f(x)|)$ (this is the [little o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)). In other words,
$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists x_0 \text{ s.t. } \forall x \ge x_0, |f(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon |f(x)|.$$

When $g(x)$ does not vanish, it is equivalent to saying that $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$$
(exercise).

You are indeed correct that $x^2 \not\sim x^2/2$, because $1/2 \neq 1$. The notation $\sim$ is restrictive on purpose, and in some situations it is helpful to have this "strict" asymptotic equivalence.

For example if $f \sim g$, then you know that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) - g(x) = 0$, and so you can now look for a function (converging to zero) such that $f - g \sim h$, etc. It's called an asymptotic expansion (similar to a Taylor series). For example, if $H_n$ is the $n$th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), then $H_n \sim \ln n$, and then $H_n - \ln n \sim \gamma$, etc. If you didn't have this strict asymptotic comparison, it would be possible to have $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) - g(x) = +\infty$.

But there is another notation that's useful, $\Theta$: by definition, $f = \Theta(g)$<sup>(1)</sup> iff $f = O(g)$ and $g = O(f)$. In other words, there exist constants $A,B > 0$ such that for big enough $x$, $|f(x)| \le A |g(x)|$ and $|g(x)| \le B |f(x)|$. It is clear that $f \sim g \implies f = \Theta(g)$. But the reverse is not true, as for example $x^2 = \Theta(x^2/2)$.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Be careful, the equality is just a notation! $\Theta(g)$ is not a function, it's actually a set. $f = \Theta(g)$ is not an equality. It's like when you write $f = o(g)$. A more correct way to write this would be $f \in \Theta(g)$: "$f$ is in the set of functions which are asymptotically bounded above and below by $g$". For historical reasons, the notation $f = \Theta(g)$ keeps getting used (and in physics I doubt you will ever see the correct notation).

Comment: Thanks a lot, merci, clear and substantial, appreciated. You proper hit the point that was puzling me the most, the fact that the definition limit of the quotient going to one applies if $g$ does not vanish . If both $f$ and $g$ vanish and infinity, e.g. $x^{-1/2}$ and $\frac{1}{2} X^{-1/2)$, the eps definition ∀ϵ>0,∃x 0  s.t. ∀x≥x 0 ,|f(x)−g(x)|<ϵ|f(x)| applies, and then one can write $f \sim g$ even if the limit of the quotient is not one.

Comment: @user37292 Um, no, you have got that wrong. When I say "$g$ does not vanish", I mean "$g(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$", not that the limit is nonzero. It is not the case that $x^{-1/2} \sim x^{-1/2}/2$, actually! Try to actually write down what the definition would mean in that case. You would need that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\sqrt{x}/2 < \epsilon\sqrt{x}$ for big enough $x$, which is not true...

Comment: I am with you, lapsus, the definition says I have a problem for $\epsilon$ samller than the teo functions ratio, thanks again.

Comment: $f \sim g$ does not imply that $f-g \to 0$.  Take $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x^2 + x$, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In some italian textbooks we use two different symbols: as $x \to x_0$

1. $f\sim g$ to mean that $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\ell \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, and
2. $f \asymp g$ to mean that $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$.

This notation is not really popular, but it helps you to understand where a multiplicative constant is not enough.